# go run command doesn't pick up non-go files in the same path

Tags: go

Folder structure:

```
- dev.env
- go.mod
- main.go
```

dev.env:

```
ENV="DEV"
PASSWORD="DEV!@#$%"
```

main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

var environment string

func init() {
    fmt.Println("ENV: ", environment)
    dir, err := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    devEnvPath := filepath.Join(dir, "dev.env")
    _ = godotenv.Load(devEnvPath)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("PASSWORD", os.Getenv("PASSWORD"))
}
```

Command:

```
go run -ldflags="-X 'main.environment=DEV'" .
```

Output:

```
ENV:  DEV
PASSWORD
```

It works with `go build` but curious why it doesn't work with `go run`

Comment: Don't ignore errors from `Load`, and print the path, `go run` builds a binary in a temp directory

Comment: @Marc You are right, the error is `{path}/exe/dev.env: no such file or directory`. How can I copy the file to that temp directory?

Comment: Don't, and don't use `go run`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, don't use `go run` unless in the most trivial of use cases - it is the most common [footgun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/footgun) in the Go community.

As @Marc pointed out the error stems from the `go run` binary is built in a temporary directory. To keep things simple, just use a relative path in your directory. This will work for both `go build` & `go run`:

```
dir := "."

devEnvPath := filepath.Join(dir, "dev.env")
err := godotenv.Load(devEnvPath)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: `go run .` is fine in general — `go run foo.go` is the more confusing pattern. In this case, it seems like the root of the problem was the assumption that `os.Args[0]` refers to the location of the source code (rather than the location of the binary).

Answer (score 1):

As of Go 1.16, the simplest way to access files from the directory containing a package's source code is to use `//go:embed` and the [`embed`](https://pkg.go.dev/embed) package to embed those files into the compiled binary:

```golang
//go:embed dev.env
var devEnv string

func init() {
    m, err := godotenv.Unmarshal(devEnv)
    …
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for something like this